# If there a way to compile (not execute) a query syntaxicly and semanticly with JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java-7

I have numerous queries which contains syntax error (and without unit test, but that's another problem) and I'd like to massively check if there are no errors.

For that, I've done the following at first:

```
String q = ...; // some query
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(q)) {
  final ParameterMetaData pmd = stmt.getParameterMetaData();
  for (int i = 1; i <= pmd.getParameterCount(); ++i) {
    stmt.setNull(i, java.sql.Types.NULL);
  }
  stmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  ...
} finally {
  connection.rollback();
}
```

It works, but then I came into such errors: http://www.oracle-error.com/11g/ORA-30081.html

Basically, somewhere in my query, I have that:

```
select * 
from   table T
where  id = ? or ( ? - INTERVAL '1' DAY ) between date_start and date_end
```

If I execute the same query, replacing `?` by `NULL`, in TOAD, I've got the same error.

The `ParameterMetaData` does not help either, because it don't store the information I want (eg: what Oracle expect as parameter).

Is there some solution to compile the query syntactically and semantically (to check for missing columns, etc) ignoring parameters along the way?

As of now, I am replacing the `?` by `NULL`, except if after the "?" I found some date stuff, where I use `sysdate`.

eg:

```
select * 
from   table T
where  id = NULL or ( sysdate - INTERVAL '1' DAY ) between date_start and date_end
```

Comment: Wrap an explicit cast around the parameter marker: `where  ( cast(? as date) - INTERVAL '1' DAY )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse SQL via Oracle's JDBC driver](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3873322/266304), apart from the focus on parameters?

Comment: @mustaccio: the problem here, is that I don't know what the parameter is. Well, as of now, I use a regexp using `matcher(q).region(end, length).lookingAt()` to see if I have some "date pattern" after the `?`.

Comment: @AlexPoole I did not think about "parse" while looking for answer. I though about "compile" :/ I'll try the `DBMS_SQL` in TOAD, but I don't see in the Oracle documentation that it handle positional parameters. Also, while I don't have a problem with Oracle specific answer, the question might also interest someone working with PostgreSQL, mySQL, etc... In that sense, I don't see it as a duplicate.

Comment: Semantic check can not be done ONLY by the database. For example BLOB column can not be used directly in where conditions. Is you're looking for some kind of rough estimate test, there is freely downloadable grammar(parser) for SQL ISO-2003.

Comment: PS: Oracle does not understand question marks as bind variable placeholders. It is JDBC  stuff. Oracle JDBC drivers internally translates them into named placeholders like ` :1, :2, ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly through JDBC, but you can do it indirectly; [heavily inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873881/266304), you can do:

```
String q = ...; // some query
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("declare c integer;
    begin
      c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      dbms_sql.parse(c,?,dbms_sql.native);
      dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
    end;")) {
  stmt.setString(1, q.replace("?", ":b0"));
  stmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  ...
}
```

The statement you prepare is now an anonymous block, and the single bind variable is now your original query to validate. You don't need to know anything about the query's parameters. The `replace` converts the JDBC `?` placeholders to generic `:b0` bind variables so the parser doesn't object to them.

You could be more advanced and replace each placeholder with a different bind variable (`:b0`, `:b1`) etc. but I don't think it will generally be necessary. This crude replace would also potentially modify string literals though, of course, which may be something you need to consider; a regular expression approach would be more robust.

Comment: Hmm, actually, maybe this is more of a straight duplicate of the linked question than I initially thought; somehow I missed that was about JDBC too, I was only looking at the PL/SQL part. This shows it can be done without creating a function, but that's hardly a revelation... You need to do something with the placeholders though.

Comment: Well I am already looking for "?" to replace them so as its stands, because the query contains specific syntax like `?...`; replacing them is not a real problem :). I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, that works :) I used a clob instead, since my queries can be big.

Answer (score 1):

One other option to try might be to use the `EXPLAIN PLAN` statement available in Oracle and in some other DBMSes (possibly in a slightly different form). Prepend `'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR '` to your statement and `execute()` (no need to prepare). The original statement won't actually run, but it will be parsed and compiled, and you don't need to bind any parameters.

[Proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5624/0).

It may still choke on untyped parameter markers in some cases though.