# Dynamic SQL - Check syntax and semantics

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

With Oracle dynamic SQL one is able to execute a string containing a SQL statement. e.g.

```
l_stmt := 'select count(*) from tab1';
execute immediate l_stmt;
```

Is it possible to not execute `l_stmt` but check that the syntax and semantics is correct programmitically?

Comment: Prepare the statement.

Comment: You can use `DBMS_SQL.PARSE()` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68277

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3873881/18747

Comment: If you use DBMS_SQL.PARSE, please be aware that this actually executes your statement if it happens to be DDL.

Comment: best way which i use to check the dynamic sql is to put logger i.e dbms_output.put to check if statement is correctly formed or not. This way no execution takes place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only "solution" is to use `DBMS_SQL.PARSE()`.

It is not perfect but it is the best that you can get

Comment: For future readers: keep in mind that for DDL statements, this will not only parse the statement, but it will execute it as well.

Answer (score 1):

[`EXPLAIN PLAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) will check the syntax and semantics of almost all types of SQL statements.  And unlike `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` it will not implicitly execute anything.

The point of the explain plan is to show how Oracle will execute a statement.  As a side-effect of generating the plan it must also check syntax, privileges, and generally do everything except actually run the statement.  The explain plan itself is pointless and can be ignored, the statement is only run to check for any errors.  As long as there are no errors, the statement is valid.

For example, the PL/SQL blocks below check the validity of a `SELECT` statement and a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  They run without error so the syntax is fine.

```
begin
    execute immediate 'explain plan for select * from dual';
end;
/

begin
    execute immediate 'explain plan for create table just_some_table(a number)';
end;
/
```

Running a bad statement will generate an error.  In at least this one test case, it generates the same error as if the statement was run by itself.

```
begin
    execute immediate 'explain plan for select * from this_table_does_not_exist';
end;
/
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The syntax diagram in the manual implies it should run for *all* statements.  However, there appear to be at least a few statement types that do not work, such as `ALTER SESSION`.

```
begin
    execute immediate 'explain plan for alter session set optimizer_features_enable = ''11.2.0.4''';
end;
/
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Slightly off-topic - are you trying to build a completely generic SQL interface, like a private SQL Fiddle built in PL/SQL?  Do you need to worry about things like preventing users from attempting to run certain statement types, and ensuring there are no trailing semicolons?  If so I can edit the question to help with some of those difficult dynamic SQL tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this way you can check the query formed before execution.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
lv_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
lv_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
lv_sql:='select count(*) from tab1';
dbms_output.put_line(lv_sql);
--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql INTO lv_cnt;
END
```

Comment: Basically i use that dbms_output printed data and run it in worksheet to avoid the run time errors. And this is very imp when we are dealing with huge dynamic queries with lots of dynamic conditions

Comment: Is there any other way without executing the dynamic sql for its semantics and syntax?

Comment: This is not getting the machine to do the work of checking the syntax or the semantics. This is you doing the inspection.

Comment: OK got it. So is there any way without execution to check this by machine?

Comment: This is what the post is asking

Comment: @AvrajitRoy - there are already links to docs and previous answers about using `dbms_sql` to do this. I think the question implies it's to *programmatically* check that the syntax and semantics is correct, though adding that clarification wouldn't hurt.