# What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server's SET NOEXEC or NOPARSE?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

I have an SQL script that updates db procedures or alter tables depending on some condition. script should work also if the procedures or tables does not exist at runtime (in such case noting should be updated).

In MSSQL I was able to achieve that with the NOEXEC, as follows:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sysobjects where name ='MY_PROC1')
  SET NOEXEC ON
GO 
--the following code will not be executed in the server 
ALTER PROCEDURE [MY_PROC1]
(
    code that alter the procedure
)
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF
GO
```

Is there an equivalent command to NOEXEC in Oracle? or an elegant way in Oracle to write similar script but w/o using "dynamic-sql". I don't want to wrap the code with quotes.

Comment: No, it's not possible afaik.  The closest you could get would be using `dbms_sql.parse()`, which you would hate, because you have to use dynamic sql + cursor. But it doesn't quite work for DDL statements anyways (such as your `alter procedure` statement), because it will also execute the statement, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL - Check syntax and semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713444/dynamic-sql-check-syntax-and-semantics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments everyone.
Unfortunately Oracle does not have equivalent command for MsSql NOEXEC :(
The workarounds suggested with `dbms_sql.parse()` or `EXPLAIN PLAN` does not fit exactly to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be rewritten as a PL/SQL block but any DDL language like alter procedure must be done as execute immediate

```
DECLARE
v_count NUMBER(9)
BEGIN
SELECT count(*)
INTO v_count
FROM all_objects
where owner = '<your schema name>'
and object_name = '<your object>';

IF v_count = 1 
THEN
--do something
ELSE
--do something else or remove the else
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks but using The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement executes a dynamic SQL statement

Comment: @Yarix even though they are both somewhat ANSI SQL compliant Oracle != Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

I do something like that

```
declare
c integer;
begin
select count(*) into c from xray where bar;

if c > 0 then
/* found, do something */
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('found, do something');
else
/* not found, do something else */
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('not found, do something else');
end if;
end;
```